# Robust rtp video streaming over IP on Linux

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, rtp, dvb, forwarderrorcorrection

I'm looking for a way to stream video in a robust way using Linux on an IP network.

I know one could use [FEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) and [RFC5109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5109) standardizes it, but I couldn't find any implementation of it.

The DVB standard uses some sort of FEC itself, but I could find only repeaters able to send the already encoded feed from a tuner to the network, not tools which encapsulate the stream adding error correction.

Does anyone know of such a tool I might add in a pipeline?